# AVPlayer couldn't launch video that fetch from remote url swift5

Tags: swift, avfoundation, swift5

sometimes asset.isPlayable() returns false, sometimes it returns true, but it take too many times. what is the cause of this?

```
        if let url = videoURL {
            self.asset = AVURLAsset(url: url)//url)
            if self.asset.isPlayable {
                let track = self.asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0]
                self.videoNaturalSize = track.naturalSize

                self.playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: self.asset)
                self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: self.playerItem)

                self.playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player)
                self.playerLayer.frame = self.videoView.bounds

                self.playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill

                if self.viewActive {
                    self.play()
                    self.replayButton.isHidden = true

                } else {
                    self.replayButton.isHidden = false
                    self.videoIndicatorView.isHidden = !self.isTraceEnable
                }

                NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.playerFinished), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.player!.currentItem)
            } else {
                self.showInfoPopup(message: "Video cannot be played right now. Try again later.")
            }
        } else {
            print(":::::::::::::: NO VIDEO URL ::::::::::::::")
        }
```